# Connecting to MariaDB via TCP returns socket error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a local installation of MariaDB 10xx via the mysql command line application but despite specifying a host and a port I get an error the client cannot connect via the unix socket.

This is my `my.cnf`:

```
⟩ sudo vi /opt/local/etc/mariadb-10.1/my.cnf

# Use default MacPorts settings
!include /opt/local/etc/mariadb-10.1/macports-default.cnf 

[mysqld]
socket=/private/tmp/mysqld.sock
port=3306

log_error=/private/tmp/mysql_error.log
log_warnings=3

general-log
general-log-file=/private/tmp/mariadb_queries.log
log-output=file
```

This is the command line I use:

```
mysql -u root --host localhost --port 3306 --password
```

And this is the error:

```
⟩ mysql -u root --host localhost --port 3306 --password
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mariadb-10.1/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I'm trying to check whether MariaDB is listening to TCP connections.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't seem to be reading the correct configuration file or at least not in the order that is needed, `socket=/private/tmp/mysqld.sock` != `socket=/opt/local/var/run/mariadb-10.1/mysqld.sock`.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked in the MariaDB IRC channel and apparently passing localhost to MariaDB causes it to use the unix socket. Replacing `--host localhost` with `--host 127.0.0.1` did the trick.